# How can I replace the navigation title in my macOS SwiftUI app with my own code?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How can I replace the `navigationTitle` with my own element?

[image: A screenshot of the top corner of the SF Symbols app with the navigation bar title highlighted in red]

Answer (score 1):

To replace the navigationTitle with your own (presumably) non-text code:

1. Hide the `navigationTitle` by setting it to an empty string.
2. Add your own toolbar elements there with the [`navigation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemplacement/navigation) placement.

---

For example, this code...

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ABC")
            .navigationTitle("")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                    Text("This is my own text!")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

...achieves this result:

[image]